# How to get search script to return search page

Tags: php, search

like google
https://www.google.com/#q=cars

I have this very simple search script but want to get a search page linking to the results of a term like If I search for cars in google i get this page
https://www.google.com/#q=cars
right now this script just returns the search results in the same page

```
<?php
  $source_dir = ".";

  $results = array();
  if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()==1) $_POST["q"]=stripslashes($_POST["q"]);
  $criteria = strtolower($_POST["q"]);

  function check_criteria($filename,$criteria){
    if($criteria=='' or $criteria=='""'){
      return false;
    }
    else{
      $criteria1=$criteria;
      if(substr($criteria,0,1)=='"' and substr($criteria,-1)=='"'){  
        $criteria1=substr($criteria,1,-1);
        if(strpos($filename,$criteria1)!==false){
          return true;
        }
      }
      elseif(strpos($criteria,' ')!==false){  
        $arr=explode(' ',$criteria);
        if($arr) foreach($arr as $val){
          $criteria1=trim($val);
          if(strpos($filename,$criteria1)!==false){
            return true;
          }
        }
      }
      else{  
        if(strpos($filename,$criteria1)!==false){
          return true;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  function find_files($mydir){
    global $results, $criteria;
    if(($tdir=@opendir($mydir))!==false){
      while($f=readdir($tdir)){
        if($f!="." and $f!=".."){
          if(is_dir($mydir."/".$f)){
            if(find_files($mydir."/".$f)>=1000) return count($results);
          }
          elseif(is_file($mydir."/".$f)){
            if(check_criteria(strtolower($f),$criteria)){
              // found!
              if(count($results)>=1000) return count($results);
              $results[]=$mydir."/".$f;             
            }
          }
        }
      }  
      closedir($tdir);
    }

    return count($results);
  }

  function format_filesize($size,$dec=1) {
    $kb = 1024;         // Kilobyte
    $mb = 1024 * $kb;   // Megabyte
    $gb = 1024 * $mb;   // Gigabyte
    $tb = 1024 * $gb;   // Terabyte


    if($size < $kb) {
      return $size." bytes";
    }
    else if($size < $mb) {
      return round($size/$kb,$dec)." kb";
    }
    else if($size < $gb) {
      return round($size/$mb,$dec)." mb";
    }
    else if($size < $tb) {
      return round($size/$gb,$dec)." gb";
    }
    else {
      return round($size/$tb,$dec)." tb";
    }
  }


?>
<html>
<head>
<title>Search Files</title>

<style>
.err {
  color: #f00;
}
label {
  font-weight: bold;
}
th {
  background-color: #ccc;
  font-weight: bold;
}
</style>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"></head>

<body bgcolor="#000000" text="#FFFFFF">
<h1>&nbsp;</h1>
<form method="post">
  <label for="q">search:</label>
  &nbsp;<input type="text" name="q" id="q" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST["q"]) ?>" size="32" maxlength="128">&nbsp;<input type="submit" name="search" value=" Search! ">
</form>

<?php

  // Search results
  if($_POST["search"]){

    echo '<hr>'."\n\n";
    echo '<h3>Search results:</h3>';

    if(strlen($_POST["q"])<1){
      echo '<p class="err">Please enter keyword.</p>';
    }
    elseif(strlen($_POST["q"])<2){
      echo '<p class="err">Keyword is too short.</p>';
    }
    else{

      $n=find_files($source_dir);
      if($n<=0){
        echo '<p>No results found.</p>';
      }
      elseif($n>=1000){
        echo '<p>Too much results, please refine your search. Displaying first <b>100</b> results:</p>';
      }
      else{
        echo '<p><b>'.$n.'</b> files found:</p>';
      }

      if($results){

        echo '<table width="500" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3" border="0">'."\n";
        echo '<tr><th align="left">File Name</th><th align="right">Size</th></tr>';

        foreach($results as $val){
          $size=filesize($val);
          echo '<tr><td align="left" valign="top" nowrap><a href="'.$val.'" target="_blank">'.basename($val).'</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td align="right" valign="top" nowrap>'.format_filesize($size).'</td></tr>'."\n";
        }

        echo '</table>'."\n";
      }

    }
  }

?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: do you mean using `$_GET` at the place of `$_POST`? `mysite.com/?q=cars` then `$criteria = strtolower($_GET["q"]);`??

Comment: You need to explain this better

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to display the results in a new page (which is what I gather from your post), do the following.

1. Create a new file, and move everything contained within `if($_POST["search"]){}` to that file. Remember the newly-created file name.
2. Add `action="NEW_NAME_HERE"` to your form tag, where NEW_NAME_HERE is the newly-created file name from step 1.

See [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.3) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form) for a bit more on `action`